# I tried this. But, How to get the number, of each letter in specified string in web page

Tags: javascript, html

How to get the number of occurrences of each letter in a specified string entered in input text field?

I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Web Page</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    body {
  background: #007bff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0062E6, #33AEFF);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = btn;

function btn() {
  document.getElementById("btn").onclick = showText;
}

function showText() {
  var text = "";
  var inputOne = document.getElementById("txtBox").value;
  var inputTwo = document.getElementById("numBox").value;
  var i=1; // to control the loop
  while (i <= inputTwo) {    // i goes from 1 to inputTwo
    text += inputOne;
    i++;
  }
  document.getElementById("showCode").innerHTML = text;
}

function Char_Counts(str1) {
var uchars = {};
str1.replace(/\S/g, function(l){uchars[l] = (isNaN(uchars[l]) ? 1 : uchars[l] + 1);});
return uchars;
}
console.log(Char_Counts("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"));

  </script>
    </head>

<body style="text-align:center;">
    <h1 style="color:green;">
        Sample Web Page
    </h1>
    <p>
        Enter Your text below:
    </p>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="txtBox"><br/> <input type="number" id="numBox"><br/><br/>
<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-warning">Click Me!</button> <br/>

<p id="showCode"></p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `let result = str1.split('').reduce((a, c) => ((c in a ? a[c] += 1 : a[c] = 1), a), {})`

Answer (score 0):

This will output a simple json string corresponding to letter counting of the string you type on the `txtBox` input field.

```
function showText() {
  var inputOne = document.getElementById("txtBox").value;
  document.getElementById("showCode").textContent = Char_Counts(inputOne);
}

function Char_Counts(str1) {
    var uchars = {};
    str1.replace(/\S/g, function(l){uchars[l] = (isNaN(uchars[l]) ? 1 : uchars[l] + 1);});
    return JSON.stringify(uchars);
}
```

You can delete `<input type="number" id="numBox">`, and `console.log(Char_Counts("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"));` from your code.